# Why are these two UPC-E values converting to the same UPC-A values?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert UPC-E to UPC-A, and I am seeing strange results. I believe they might be correct, because two reference sites I have found show the same conversion, but I thought UPC-E should convert distinctly to UPC-A.

Both of 678905 and 678954 are converting to 067890000053.

When I check these on the number converter at http://www.morovia.com/education/utility/upc-ean.asp, I see the same, but when I convert from 067890000053, it becomes 678954.

I see the same thing here: http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/symbologies/upc

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPC-E#UPC-E

Yup, it looks like your example just happens to be a case where, two different UPC-E codes expand to the same UPC-A.
In fact, this will happen for any pairs of the forms
XXXX54 - XXXX05,
XXX063 - XXX006,
XX0072 - XX2007,
XX0081 - XX1008,
and possibly others.

Sorry.